# How to check if all my XML elements are in sequence using XSLT's position()?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

My XML looks like below:

```
<test>
    <a>1</a>
    <a>2</a>
    <a>3</a>
    <a>4</a>
    <a>5</a>
</test>
```

Elements are in sequence? `True? .

```
<test>
    <a>1</a>
    <a>5</a>
    <a>3</a>
    <a>2</a>
    <a>6</a>
</test>
```

Elements are in sequence? `False`.

How we can achive this with the help of `Position` available in XSLT?

Comment: Why do you want to use `position()`, why don't you write a predicate for `test` that compares each `a` child element to its preceding sibling?

Comment: If your aim is to sort all a nodes, you can use `xsl:sort`

Comment: Would `<a>1</a><a>3</a><a>4</a>` be considered in sequence here?

Comment: Would `<a>9</a><a>10</a><a>11</a>` be considered in sequence - i.e. is this a numeric or an alphabetical sort? (NOTE: trying to define a general property "is in sequence" by one example sequence that has the property and another example sequence that doesn't is intrinsically doomed to failure. Please make some attempt to define the problem more rigorously.)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend use of a recursive template here: apply-templates to the first item in the sequence, and from there apply-templates to `following-sibling::*[1]`, passing the current value as a parameter; in each call, test whether the new value is greater than the old. Terminate with a return value of false if it's not, terminate with a return value of true if you hit the end of the sequence.

I can't see why calling `position()` would in any way be useful.